# Split a JSON array into multiple files

Tags: files, json, jq

I have a file that looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "billingAccountNumber": "x",
    "paymentResponseObject": {
      "uiErrorDipslayMessage": "",
      "transactionStatus": "S",
      "transactionDescription": "",
      "transactionCode": "",
      "confirmationNumber": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "billingAccountNumber": "y",
    "paymentResponseObject": {
      "uiErrorDipslayMessage": "",
      "transactionStatus": "S",
      "transactionDescription": "",
      "transactionCode": "",
      "confirmationNumber": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "billingAccountNumber": "z",
    "paymentResponseObject": {
      "uiErrorDipslayMessage": "",
      "transactionStatus": "S",
      "transactionDescription": "",
      "transactionCode": "",
      "confirmationNumber": "3"
    }
  }
]
```

The data doesn't look exactly like this, and I have more than three elements.  From this data, I want to create three files: `x.json`, `y.json`, and `z.json`.  I want the contents of each of those files to be the contents of the `paymentResponseObject`.

Is there a way to do this with `jq`?  I've figured out how to do this in `awk`, but it's very clunky and I want to be able to repeat this process with different schemas.  I have to rewrite 80% of the `awk` script for each schema.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503531/8239155) SO thread:

```
jq -cr 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)\n\(.[$k])"' input.json | while read -r key; do
  fname=$(jq --raw-output ".[$key].billingAccountNumber" input.json)
  read -r item
  printf '%s\n' "$item" > "./$fname"
done
```

Comment: Thanks.  What does `"\($k)\n\(.[$k])"` do?

Comment: NP.  It prints the object key, a newline, and then the object itself.

Answer (score 3):

Give a try with this code to save each element with names `0.json`, `1.json` and `2.json`. FYI, it can work for any number of JSON items in an array.

```bash
for i in $(seq $(jq '.|length' sample.json)); do \
    j=$( expr $i - 1 ); \
    jq ".[$j]" sample.json > $j.json;  \
done
```

**Explanation:**

below line finds the length of array to name the objects:

```bash
$(seq $(jq '.|length' sample.json))
```

Since the array starts with 0, lets fix the output file name

```bash
j=$( expr $i - 1 );
```

below lines fetches one element from json document and save to file

```bash
jq ".[$j]" sample.json > $j.json;
```

to save literally to `x.json`, `y.json` and `z.json`:

```bash
for i in x y z; do \
  jq ".[$count]" sample.json > $i.json;  \
  count=$( expr $count + 1 ) \
done
```

Comment: thanks @AdminBee for the edit/re-format; looks better now.

Comment: All part of the service ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make `jq` create a shell script for you:

```bsh
jq -r '.[] |
    @sh "cat >\(.billingAccountNumber).json <<\\END",
    .paymentResponseObject,
    "END"' file.json
```

This takes each top-level array element in your JSON document and creates a shell here-document redirection for each.  Each redirection into `cat` is quoted to avoid that the shell expands things in the document. The output goes to the file named by the `.billingAccountNumber` value, quoted by the `@sh` formatter in `jq`.

Given the data in the question, this creates the script

```bsh
cat >'x'.json <<\END
{
  "uiErrorDipslayMessage": "",
  "transactionStatus": "S",
  "transactionDescription": "",
  "transactionCode": "",
  "confirmationNumber": "1"
}
END
cat >'y'.json <<\END
{
  "uiErrorDipslayMessage": "",
  "transactionStatus": "S",
  "transactionDescription": "",
  "transactionCode": "",
  "confirmationNumber": "2"
}
END
cat >'z'.json <<\END
{
  "uiErrorDipslayMessage": "",
  "transactionStatus": "S",
  "transactionDescription": "",
  "transactionCode": "",
  "confirmationNumber": "3"
}
END
```

This could be run by `sh` to create the three files `x.json`, `y.json`, and `z.json` using the three embedded and quoted here-documents.

Running this would be a matter of piping it into `sh -s` directly from `jq`.